# I want to duplicate my WordPress website, but how do i deal with the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, duplicates

I wish to duplicate my current website so I can play around and try new ideas, before putting them on my live site. The reason I want to duplicate is so I have all of the content etc, so I can see how it really looks. I understand I can just copy my entire WordPress install into another directory, but what do I do with my database?

Currently my WordPress is installed into the root directory, I will simple create a new directory called Dev. Then simple just add /Dev to my URL and voila, I can view my duplicated website.

But how do I deal with my database? I am using a MySQL database, hosted with GoDaddy.

(I want to change my hosting from GoDaddy to someone else once the renewal is up, mainly because of their support for SOPA. anyway that's for another time...)

Comment: I'd advise you to play around with your site on your local machine, rather than on your remote host. If you have SSH access, use `mysql_dump` or similar to take a copy of the database and then `scp` it to your local machine. This can be automated on the command line. If you don't have SSH, use the host's install of phpMyAdmin to take a snapshot instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way with GoDaddy is to log into your account, go to your hosting management and click the databases tab at the top and then look for phpMyAdmin.

Once in phpMyAdmin, go to the wordpress database and select the operations tab at the top and then use the "Copy database to:" feature.

If your version of phpMyAdmin doesn't show the copy database feature, you can export all tables of the database and import them into your duplicate database.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you have phpMyAdmin installed, you may export your wordpress database, then create a new database and import the .sql file you just exported. Next, configure the copied wordpress to use your new database. The configuration is in wp-config.php. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers here i suggest you export your DB via phpmyadmin if can. You will however notice that all image URLS point to the old domain. To fix this run a find and replace script. I usually use this one: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess around with a new utility like phpmyadmin, you can install a wordpress plugin to back up your database. Then you can copy your files anywhere and use the same plugin to restore the database. I personally use [UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore](http://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/).

It should be noted that moving your site to a new folder or domain will break a lot of the database data. A simple search and replace is not enough to fix it.

For more information, you can go here: [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)